# Angular material input type datetime-local doesn't show today's date

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular material and in that input `type="datetime-local"`:

```
<input
  matInput
  type="datetime-local"
  placeholder="Next Date"
  class="date-picker"
  [formControl]="ndate"
/>
```

But the problem is when I am opening that date time picker it is showing the date from January 0001. See the below image for that:

[image]

And I want to show today's date.

Is there any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: Which angular version you have?

Comment: can you share formcontrol nddate definition pls, try to set current date for nddate

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the line `type="datetime-local"`